# Why $x^2 = -i $ 's solutions are $(1/\sqrt{(2)})(-1 + i)$ and $(1/\sqrt{(2)})(1- i)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Can someone explain why $x^2 = -i $ 's solutions are $(1/\sqrt{(2)})(-1 + i)$ and $(1/\sqrt{(2)})(1- i)$  in the complex numbers.

Why the solutions are not simply : $-\sqrt{i}$ and $\sqrt{i}$ ?

Comment: What _is_ $\sqrt {-i}$?

Comment: I actually don't know

Comment: Well... $\pm i\sqrt i$ is a solution. But it is not in reduced form.

Comment: What does $\sqrt{\vphantom i \hphantom -}$ mean, usually?

Comment: it should mean $ -i^2 = \sqrt{-i}$ ?

Comment: Square root of an imaginary number is really well-defined. To combat this, substitute $x=a+bi$.

Comment: Don't understand the down votes.  This seems like a very valid question for this website to me

Comment: One more solution for the geometrically minded.  If you draw an arrow from the origin to the point $x$ in the complex plane, squaring corresponds to squaring the length and doubling the angle with the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, your suggested solutions aren't solutions: $(\pm\sqrt{i})^2=i$, not $-i$.

To use that sort of notation, the solutions would be $\pm\sqrt{-i}$. But the whole problem is, what are those numbers?

There are many ways to solve $x^2=-i$. Note that if $a+bi$ is one solution, then the other solution is just its opposite, $-a-bi$. So start by assuming $a+bi$ is a solution (where $a$ and $b$ are real) and try to find $a$ and $b$.

In particular, we are assuming that
$$(a+bi)^2 = -i$$
$$a^2+2abi +b^2i^2 = -i$$
$$a^2+2abi-b^2 = -i$$
Moving everything to the left side, and grouping real and imaginary terms,
$$(a^2-b^2) + i(2ab+1) = 0$$
This is true if and only if the real part and the imaginary part are both zero:
$$\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2 = 0 \\
2ab +1 = 0
\end{cases}$$
(Note that we can immediately say that neither $a$ nor $b$ can be zero, since the second equation would become $1=0$, which is false.)
We can solve the second equation for $b$ in terms of $a$ to get
$$b = -\frac1{2a}$$
Putting that back into the first equation, we have
$$a^2 - \left(-\frac1{2a}\right)^2 = 0$$
$$a^2-\frac1{4a^2}=0$$
Since $a\neq 0$, we can multiply both sides by $4a^2$ to get
$$4a^4-1=0$$ Factor as a difference of squares:
$$(2a^2+1)(2a^2-1)=0$$
Set each factor equal to zero to find all possible solutions:

**First factor:**
$$2a^2+1=0 \iff a^2=-\frac12\textrm{ (no real solution)}$$

**Second factor:**
$$2a^2+1=0 \iff a^2=\frac12 \iff a = \pm\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$$
The corresponding values of $b$ are (note the sign reversal)
$$b = - \frac1{2a} = \mp\frac{1}{2\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt2}}
=\mp\frac1{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}}=\mp\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
=\mp\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}} = \mp\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So, in the end, we have $a=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ as one solution and $a=-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$  as the other solution. In other words, we have the two solutions
$$a+bi = \pm\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\pm(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
These are exactly the solutions $(1-i)/\sqrt{2}$ and $(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}$ you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Because they satisfy the equation.

Example of verifying the first solution.
\begin{align}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1+i)\right)^2&=\frac12 (-1+i)(-1+i)\\&=\frac12 \left((-1)(-1)-i-i+i^2 \right)\\
&=\frac12 \left( 1-2i-1 \right)\\
&=\frac12 (-2i) \\
&= -i
\end{align}

Edit:

$$x^2=-i=\exp(2\pi n -\frac{\pi}{2}), n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$x=-i=\exp(\pi n -\frac{\pi}{4}), n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Let $n=0$ and $n=1$,

$x=\exp(-\frac{\pi}{4})$ or $x=\exp(\frac{3\pi}{4})$

That is

$x =\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4})+i \sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})$ or $x =\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+i \sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})$

Comment: ok, but using which formula do I find the solution starting from $x^2 = -i$, thank you

Comment: @JJAb The usual quadratic formula works, once you rewrite to $x^2+i=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much to both

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten several good answers. But part of it comes down to the fact that when dealing with a complex number, $a + bi$, square roots, in fact any nth root,  can be reduced to another complex number. That is, for any real $a$ and $b$,  $\sqrt{a + bi} = c + di$ for some real $c$ and $d$.