# What's the value of $\sqrt{-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to find the value of $\sqrt{-i}$. And i made two attempts which gave me two answers.

**Method -1**

$$\sqrt{-i}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{i}=i\sqrt{i}=i^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
But $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Putting it in we get that,
$$\sqrt{-i}=e^{\frac{3\pi}{4}i}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$$

**Method-2**

Note that $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$

Using that we get
$$\sqrt{-i}=e^{-i\pi/4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Why are the answers in both the methods different?

Comment: Each non-zero complex number has two distinct square roots. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Complex_roots).

Comment: The square root of complex numbers does not have a natural choice of $+$ vs $-$.

Comment: Notice that $e^{i 3\pi/2} = -i$ as well so you have to make a choice.

Comment: to check if $a$ is a square root of $-i$ you should check if $a\cdot a=-i$

Comment: The complex square root is a multiple valued function. You need the notion of complex logarithm to define that. But speaking more simply, it does not matter what value you get, see that it squares to $-i$ . That is sufficient.

Comment: Related, if not duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376738/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2076299/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212615/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2460036/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%7B-%5Cexact%7Bi%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the comments, for a fixed complex number $z_0$ the equation $z^2 = z_0$ will always have two distinct complex solutions (unless $z_0 = 0$, in which case there is one repeated solution).

One way to compute the square root (and $n$-th roots in general) is to use polar form, as you use for $i$ and $-i$ respectively. Indeed, you are correct to observe that $e^{-i\pi/2} = -i$, but that is not the only way of expressing $-i$ in polar form. Though the principal argument of $-i$ is $-\pi/2$, we also have $3\pi/2$ as an argument for $-i$, and in general $-\pi/2 + 2n\pi$ will be a valid argument for $-i$ for any integer $n$.

So fix an argument $\theta_0$ and consider the two expressions:

$$\big(e^{i\theta_0}\big)^{1/2} \quad\text{and}\quad \big(e^{i\theta_0 + 2\pi i}\big)^{1/2}$$

The first simplifies to $e^{i\theta_0/2}$, what we might think of as the "principal root", while the second simplifies to $e^{i\theta_0/2 +\pi i} = e^{i\theta_0/2} e^{i\pi} = - e^{i\theta_0/2}$. You are actually familiar with this result already, as it is true even for real numbers: if $a^2 = b$ then $\sqrt{b} = \pm a$.

The above trick can be generalized to $n$-th roots, which yields the following slick result: if $a^n = b$ then $\sqrt[n]{b} = \omega a$, where $\omega$ is any one of the $n$, $n$-th roots of unity: those numbers $\omega_m = e^{i\pi m/n}$ for $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$.